# How to initiate UIProgressView to a certain value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiprogressview

Would it be in the .h or .m and how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would definitely be in the `.m` file.

Initialize your UIProgressView, and then call `setProgress:` on it.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [loadValue setProgress:(float) 0.0];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

in the .m

Answer (score 12):

As defined in the [`UIProgressView` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIProgressView/progress), `UIProgressView` has a `progress` property. Just set that when you create your view:

```
UIProgressView *view = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:whateverStyle];
view.progress = 0.75f;
// Do whatever you want with the view
// (and don't forget to -release it later)
```

would initialize a `UIProgressView` with its progress value set to 75%

Answer (score 0):

The .h—“header”—file is usually where information about your class goes... its structure, “what it does” rather than “how it does it”. The .m is thus probably the right place, but it'd help for you to go into more detail about how your UI is set up. Are you using Interface Builder or creating the UIProgressView programmatically? Is the class a view, a view controller, the application's delegate, or what?