# Animate progress bar in XCode for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to initiate UIProgressView to a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938487/how-to-initiate-uiprogressview-to-a-certain-value)

I would like to create a simple progress bar animation in XCode. So, when I open page it should animate to the specific percentage. I am not that familiar with XCode, that's why I ask here. I tried to google that, but no specific solution. Is there any advice on this? I also have looked at some advises here at SO, but no luck.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UIProgressView has a method to set it's progress with animation.
 Just call that when you create your view:

```
UIProgressView *view = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:someStyle];
[view setProgress:0.7 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Make sure you're on the main thread when you perform the setProgress:animated: calls or it won't update.